# Rename categorical values python statsmodels

Tags: python, model, rename, statsmodels

Is there a way to change the format C(Location, Treatment("China"))[T.America] to something more readable like the expected output below?

Thanks a lot for your help

```
y ~ C(Location, Treatment(reference='China'))
          
======================================================================================
                         coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept             51.6784      0.982     52.619      0.000      49.741      53.615
C(Location, Treatment("China"))[T.America]    11.5417      3.286      3.512      0.001       5.061      18.022
C(Location, Treatment("China"))[T.Japan]     -9.8000      3.388     -2.893      0.004     -16.481      -3.119
C(Location, Treatment("China"))[T.Australia]      5.8552      2.153      2.720      0.007       1.610      10.101
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       10.487   Durbin-Watson:                   1.779
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.005   Jarque-Bera (JB):               11.031
Skew:                          -0.551   Prob(JB):                      0.00402
Kurtosis:                       2.670   Cond. No.                         8.30
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Expected output

```
                         
======================================================================================
                         coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept             51.6784      0.982     52.619      0.000      49.741      53.615
Location (ref=China): America     11.5417      3.286      3.512      0.001       5.061      18.022
Location : Japan    -9.8000      3.388     -2.893      0.004     -16.481      -3.119
Location :Australia    5.8552      2.153      2.720      0.007       1.610      10.101
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       10.487   Durbin-Watson:                   1.779
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.005   Jarque-Bera (JB):               11.031
Skew:                          -0.551   Prob(JB):                      0.00402
Kurtosis:                       2.670   Cond. No.                         8.30
==============================================================================
```

Comment: it's just like an index in a pandas dataframe, you can just rename the index.